# How to create a cover page for my report in Lyx?

Tags: graphics, lyx, covers

I want to create a cover page for my report.

The page should contain the

- university name,
- the course name,
- my name,
- id,
- and date....

I tried ctrl+Enter after the first line of the title to create a multi-line title but only the last line appear in the final PDF file.

- I also don't want other things from the report to appear in the cover
  page.
- I also want to include an image in the cover page.
- And I don't
  want the date that appears automatically after the title to appear.
  How can I do that, please?

Comment: It might be easier if you broke up this question into specific questions and if you provided minimal examples (see wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample). For example, to suppress the date go to Document > Settings and check the box "Suppress default date on front page".

Comment: Look at http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/title-pages or http://www.howtotex.com/templates/ for some examples.  Used a simple google search for 'latex template'.  Additionally you can search this site for '"title page" lyx' for some 'lyx' specific advice.

Answer (score 2):

1. As R.Schumacher said. I would use a template from latextemplates.com and then add the title-page to my pdf via an external software that adds 2 pdf together.
2. \begin{titlepage}
   ...
   \end{titlepage}

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation read into it and add it into your report.

3. latextemplates.com also has report templates with a title page in them.

Comment: But latextemplates.com doesn't offer templates for Lyx.

Answer (score 1):

LyX doesn't have have environments for coverpages or titlepages, so you would have to use some ERT code [evil red text] to define how you want it to look.

```
% start ERT code
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{path/filename}
... (whatever LaTeX or TeX formatting you like)  
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents % if you need one
\mainmatter
% end ERT code
```

If you find yourself using a lot of ERT code, then you're better off using a typical LaTeX editor, like Kile.  LyX can do some amazing things.  Then again, it can make some other things amazingly difficult to understand, for instance, setting the document class should be up front and center, very noticeable, instead it's buried within menus to adjust.  Someone new to LaTeX (that uses LyX) might never even realize what a class is, or understand that it's something that even needs to be defined.  That's a huge mistake on the part of LyX, not putting the class upfront and center on every document, in my opinion.